# Who exactly is "him" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *The Old Guard (2020)*, Nile joins immportal team:

> Genova: It used to take years to track a new one.  Booker was the
> last. 1812.<
>
> Nile: No way.
>
> Booker: Yeah, I died fighting with Napoleon.
>
> (Nile looks both Genova & Booker)
>
> Genova: So... you're even older than **him**.

Who exactly is "him" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genova is older than Booker. Andy is older than Genova.